# compare two data.table cell by cell in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have two data tables, `dt1` and `dt2`, where the first two columns represent chromosome and position, and the remaining columns represent genotype values (0, 1, 2) for different samples.

The column structure is the same in both tables (dt1 and dt2 have same sample), but the positions may not be identical.

```
dt1 <- data.table(Chromosome = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr2"),
                  Position = c(100, 200, 300),
                  Sample1 = c(0, 0, 1),
                  Sample2 = c(1, 1, 2))

dt2 <- data.table(Chromosome = c("chr1", "chr2", "chr2"),
                  Position = c(200, 300, 400),
                  Sample1 = c(0, 1, 2),
                  Sample2 = c(0, 1, 0))
```

I want to create a third table, `dt3`, with chromosome and position as the first two columns. The position column in dt3 should include all positions present in either dt1 or dt2. For each position, the remaining columns should represent sample names, and the cells should be marked as 1 if the genotype differs between the two tables or if the genotype exists in one table but not in the other; otherwise, the cells should be marked as 0.

The table is large, so I'm looking forward to using some feature of data.table or R for efficient processing

Expect output:

```
dt3
   Chromosome Position Sample1 Sample2
1:       chr1      100       1       1 # chr1:100 only exist in dt1
2:       chr1      200       0       1 # chr1:200 is difference in sample2
3:       chr2      300       0       1 # chr2: 300 is difference in sample 2
3:       chr2      400       1       1 # chr2:400 only exist in dt2
```

======update=======

Thanks for @Andy Baxter and @Rstudent's kendly help, I found that following code may could work, even when colname names is uncertain

```
dt1
dt2

# Andy Baxter's comment
dt3 <- merge(
  dt1,
  dt2,
  all = TRUE,
  by = c("Chromosome", "Position")
)

# target_sample is the sample name in colnames
#Rstudent's code
for(sample_name in target_sample){
    dt3[, (sample_name) := as.integer(!mapply(..identical, get(paste0(sample_name, '.x')), get(paste0(sample_name, '.y'))))][
        , c(paste0(sample_name, '.x'), paste0(sample_name, '.y')) := NULL ]
}
```

But it seems that when the data is large, there is still some problem with speed, and I don't know how to solve it further

Comment: I've edited my solution slightly to do a vectorised comparison across all paired values which *should* be able to handle millions of rows in a matter of seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you also tagged this `dplyr`, there's a handy way of creating a `data.table` solution using `dplyr` syntax. The `dtplyr` package will write (and apply) the `data.table` code for you:

```r
library(data.table)


dt1 <- data.table(Chromosome = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr2"),
                  Position = c(100, 200, 300),
                  Sample1 = c(0, 0, 1),
                  Sample2 = c(1, 1, 2))

dt2 <- data.table(Chromosome = c("chr1", "chr2", "chr2"),
                  Position = c(200, 300, 400),
                  Sample1 = c(0, 1, 2),
                  Sample2 = c(0, 1, 0))


library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(dtplyr)

dt1 |> 
  lazy_dt() |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(Chromosome, Position), names_to = "column_match", values_to = "val") |> 
  full_join(
    dt2 |> 
      pivot_longer(cols = -c(Chromosome, Position), names_to = "column_match", values_to = "val"),
    by = c("Chromosome", "Position", "column_match")
  ) |> 
  replace_na(list(val.x = -1, val.y = -1)) |> 
  mutate(val = as.integer(val.x != val.y), .keep = "unused") |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = column_match, values_from = val)
#> Source: local data table [4 x 4]
#> Call:   dcast(merge(melt(`_DT1`, measure.vars = c("Sample1", "Sample2"
#> ), variable.name = "column_match", value.name = "val", variable.factor = FALSE), 
#>     `_DT2`, all = TRUE, by.x = c("Chromosome", "Position", "column_match"
#>     ), by.y = c("Chromosome", "Position", "column_match"), allow.cartesian = TRUE)[, 
#>     `:=`(val.x = fcoalesce(val.x, -1), val.y = fcoalesce(val.y, 
#>         -1))][, `:=`(val = as.integer(val.x != val.y))][, `:=`(c("val.x", 
#> "val.y"), NULL)], formula = Chromosome + Position ~ column_match, 
#>     value.var = "val")
#> 
#>   Chromosome Position Sample1 Sample2
#>   <chr>         <dbl>   <int>   <int>
#> 1 chr1            100       1       1
#> 2 chr1            200       0       1
#> 3 chr2            300       0       1
#> 4 chr2            400       1       1
#> 
#> # Use as.data.table()/as.data.frame()/as_tibble() to access results
```

This works by:

- pivoting both data.tables to be able to join them by column names (rather than duplicate columns) and do a comparison in the new joined dataframe.
- replaces NAs with `-1` to make comparisons
- compares each set of paired values using `!=` - this will evaluate to `FALSE` if there's any -1s or if the values differ, which `!` then turns round to TRUE (`as.integer` makes this a 1 or a 0)
- the result is pivoted back to a wider data.table to look like the one you want.

This will now create a new table from any set of matching column names:

```r
dt3 <- merge(
  melt(
    dt1,
    id.vars = c("Chromosome", "Position"),
    variable.name = "column_match",
    value.name = "val"
  ),
  melt(
    dt2,
    id.vars = c("Chromosome", "Position"),
    variable.name = "column_match",
    value.name = "val"
  ),
  all = TRUE,
  by = c("Chromosome", "Position", "column_match")
) 

dt3[, `:=`(val.x = fcoalesce(val.x, -1), 
           val.y = fcoalesce(val.y, -1))
    ][, val := as.integer(val.x != val.y)
    ][, `:=`(c("val.x", "val.y"), NULL)]


dt3 <- dcast(dt3, formula = Chromosome + Position ~ column_match, value.var = "val")

dt3
#>    Chromosome Position Sample1 Sample2
#> 1:       chr1      100       1       1
#> 2:       chr1      200       0       1
#> 3:       chr2      300       0       1
#> 4:       chr2      400       1       1
```

Comment: Hi, @Andy Baxter, Thanks for your kindly help, Its code is work well, could your please share more detail about first code, Its seem that `|>` is a new pipe tools different from `%>%`, and when colnames (sample names) of dt1 and dt2 is uncertain, how to optimize the code of dt3

Comment: Hi Zhang - will add more detail as I've put in a few functions and syntax which might be unfamiliar. Yes `|>` is the new base R pipe which functions a lot like the magrittr `%>%` pipe and substitutes fairly seamlessly into `tidyverse`-style programming. Will also look at how to make code work for any/all unspecified column names!

Comment: Have updated to a new solution to try out. The speed issue may well be that the comparison part takes a long time to loop over all things. Trying outside of a `for` loop if possible might be a good solution.

Comment: The code seems a bit issye in my enviroment in fcoalesce `Error in fcoalesce(val.y, as.character(-1)) : 
  Item 2 is type character but the first item is type integer. Please coerce before coalescing.`

Comment: sorry, I change it to `dt3[, `:=`(val.x = fcoalesce(val.x, as.integer(-1)), 
                   val.y = fcoalesce(val.y, as.integer(-1)))`, its work well now, thank you

Comment: Out of curiosity I also tried it on a data.table of 1,000,000 rows and it did indeed work in a matter of seconds! Glad it helped, and hope it proves useful!